# Why does garbage collector process finalizable objects separately?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, clr

I am reading Jeffrey Richter's book "CLR via c#". It is quote from there:

> Finalize methods are called at the completion of a garbage collection on objects that the GC 
>   has determined to be garbage. This means that the memory for these objects cannot be reclaimed 
>   right away because the Finalize method might execute code that accesses a field.
>   Because a finalizable object must survive the collection, it gets promoted to another generation, forcing the object 
>   to live much longer than it should

It misled me a little bit. Why cannot finalizable object be reclaimed right away? I cannot understand argument that finalize method might execute code that accesses a field. What is problem? Moreover, I cannot understand why finalizable object should be moved to older generation and stored in separated queue (to be processed in other finalizer thread).

In my opinion the simplest way is to finalize object before removing at all without these additional actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why cannot finalizable object be reclaimed right away? I cannot understand argument that finalize method might execute code that accesses a field. What is problem?

1. Because `Finalize()` is just a normal method of the object, so code in it might access any fields of the object.
2. When garbage collection happens, all threads are frozen.

The two points add up together to the fact that when gc is happening, it cannot execute the `Finalize()` method right away (All threads are paused during gc!!), while `Finalize` is expected to be invoked before object being collected.

All these above leads to the fact that garbage collection cannot kill the object immediately before its `Finalize()` method is invoked. So gc takes the object out from the "death list" (the object is now said to be *resurrected*), and put it to a queue called "Freachable" ("**F**" stands for finalization, "**reachable**" means all objects in it cannot be garbage collected now since gc only collects objects **unreachable** from roots).

After the gc finished, a special dedicated thread with high priority will take out each entry from the "Freachable" queue and invoke `Finalize()` method on it, which makes that object finally "garbage collectable", but of course, since the first gc has already ended before this `Finalize()` calling process, all the objects poped out from "Freachable" can now only be scheduled to next garbage collection.

> Moreover, I cannot understand why finalizable object should be moved to older generation and stored in separated queue (to be processed in other finalizer thread).

To understand this, you need to first know the concept of the [generation gc model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx#generations). After objects are popped out from the "Freachable" queue and are again ready for garbage collection, they have been moved to older generation owing to the fact that they survive the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

I think this quote says "finish your unit of work stuff and kill your instance. To kill your instance you should clean up your garbage collection because of your memory."